# How to compute this integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to compute  this integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}dx$?
One method I have thought before is to solve the equation
$x^2-x-1=0$and thus get its roots $x_{1,2}=\frac{\sqrt{5}\pm 1}{2}$,let
$\phi=\frac{\sqrt{5}+ 1}{2}$.
Using the formula
$$\int \frac{\ln x}{x-a}=\ln x\ln(1-\frac{x}{a})+{L_i}_2(\frac{x}{a}),$$
we get $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}dx
=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}({L_i}_2(\frac1\phi)-{L_i}_2(-\phi)).$$
By reference to the following results 
$${L_i}_2(\frac1\phi)=\frac1{10}\pi^2-\ln ^2\phi,{L_i}_2(-\phi)=-\frac1{10}\pi^2-\ln ^2\phi,$$
we can get

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{x^2-x-1}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{5\sqrt{5}}.$$
This method relies on the property of Polylogarithm(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm),  and it looks dull.Can someone give any "cleverer"method which is not ralated to Polylogarithm?Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with Residue methods

Comment: Any more hints?I have tried with Residue methods,but it's hard to work it out.

Comment: i think there is a fractional linear transformation involved which contains the golden ratio at some point, but i can't pin it down at the moment :/

Comment: I can get the integral to the series
$$
\sum_{q=0}^\infty (-1)^{1+q} \frac{\Gamma(q+1)^2}{\Gamma(2+2q)}\left( H_q-H_{1+2q}\right)
$$
which seems to equal $\pi^2/\sqrt{5^3}$ but I can't prove that step.

Comment: Not very helpful, but the integral is equal to: $$\frac{2 \ln 2}{\sqrt{5}} \ln \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-u^2) du}{5-u^2}$$